# using an expression as table name in sqlite

Tags: sqlite

I am trying to check if a table exists prior to send a SELECT query  on that table.
The table name is composed with a trailing 2 letters language code and when I get the full table name with the user's language in it, I don't know if the user language is actually supported by my database and if the table for that language really exists.

```
SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE name = 'mytable_zz' OR name = 'mytable_en' ORDER BY ( name = 'mytable_zz' ) DESC LIMIT 1;
```

and then

```
SELECT * FROM table_name_returned_by_first_query;
```

I could have a first query to check the existence of the table like the one above, which returns mytable_zz if that table exists or mytable_en if it doesn't, and then make a second query using the result of the first as table name.

But I would rather have it all in one single query that would return the expected results from either the user's language table or the english one in case his language is not supported, without throwing a "table mytable_zz doesn't exist" error.

Anyone knows how I could handle this ?
Is there a way to use the result of the first query as a table name in the 2nd ?

edit : I don't have the hand of the database itself which is generated automatically, I don't want to get involved in a complex process of manually updating any new database that I get. Plus this query is called multiple times and having to retrieve the result of a first query before launching a second one is too long. I use plain text queries that I send through a SQLite wrapper.  I guess the simplest would rather be to check if the user's language is supported once for all in my program and store a string with either the language code of the user or "en" if not supported, and use that string to compose my table name(s). I am going to pick that solution unless someone has a better idea

Here is a simple MRE :

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `lng_en` ( key TEXT, value TEXT );
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `lng_fr` ( key TEXT, value TEXT );
INSERT INTO `lng_en` ( key , value ) VALUES ( 'question1', 'What is your name ?');
INSERT INTO `lng_fr` ( key , value ) VALUES ( 'question1', 'Quel est votre nom ?');
SELECT `value` FROM lng_%s WHERE `key` = 'question1';
```

where %s is to be replaced by the 2 letters language code. This example will work if the provided code is 'en' or 'fr' but will throw an error if the code is 'zh', in this case I would like to have the same result returned as with 'en' ....

Comment: Is there a chance to change the database structure? I am afraid that we are looking at a https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem It would mean that achieving your goal the way you plan might be very hard, if not impossible, while it could be easy if you can take one step back and approach from a different angle. If you can change the database structure everything gets easy. Consider providing a MRE of what you have (as described here https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sqlite/info ) to make helping you easier.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I thought my question would have a simple solution that didn't involve any testing by someone else. I am adding a MRE to my question. Note that this MRE is much simpler than my real issue as I need to return more than just one column from the final query

Comment: it's in the main question here above

Comment: Sorry. I somehow completely missed it.

Answer (score 0):

Not in SQL, without executing it dynamically.. But if this is your front end that is running this SQL then it doesn't matter so much. Because your table name came out of the DB there isn't really any opportunity for SQL injection hacking with it:

```
var tabName = db.ExecuteScalar("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE name = 'mytable_zz' OR name = 'mytable_en' ORDER BY ( name = 'mytable_zz' ) DESC LIMIT 1;")

var results = db.ExecuteQuery("SELECT * FROM " + tabName);
```

Yunnosch's comment is quite pertinent; you're essentially storing in a table name information that really should be in a column.. You could consider making a single table and then a bunch of views like `mytable_zz` the definition of which is `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE lang = 'zz'` etc, and make instead-of triggers if you want to cater for a legacy app that you cannot change; the legacy app would select from / insert into the views thinking they are tables, but in reality your data is single table and easier to manage

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What I falsely dubbed as tables are in fact views that mixes raw data columns from one table with human readable columns coming from another 'translation' table with a language column holding the 2 characters language code. And that gave me the clue. All I need to do is to make a new single view based on the same prototype as any of the language specific views but with all the languages instead of just keeping one with an extra column holding the language code so it be much easier to handle. Thanks